# Selecting parent next in jquery

Tags: jquery, find, parent-child, parent, closest

How can I select the parent next element in jquery

```
<div class="test">
 <table>
  <tr><td><div><a href="#" class="first">First</a></div></td></tr>
  <tr><td><div><a href="#" class="second">Second</a></div></td></tr>
 </table>
 <table>
  <tr><td class"toHide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do   eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td></tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

I have to hide `toHide` td when I click on the `first` anchor tag. How do I do that ? I have prepared a jquery code but it fails !

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".first").click(function(){
    $(this).closest('.test').find('.toHide').hide();
  });
});
```

This is done thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/aaEFQ/60/

Comment: What does "it fails" mean? Please learn to ask questions that are actually answerable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had error in `class` attributes definitions- missing and additional `=` like `class=="test"` and `class"toHide"`

```
<div class="test">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div><a href="#" class="first">First</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div><a href="#" class="second">Second</a>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td class="toHide">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/GZpHE/)

Answer (score 1):

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aaEFQ/58/)

Typo you have `==` in your html

```
<div class=="test">
           ^
```

change it to

```
<div class="test">
          ^
```

and in `<td class="toHide">` missing `=`

```
              ^
```

Comment: But I have many divs in the same ID (or Class). I have to ide the respective 'toHide' td

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  jQuery('#test .toHide').hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".first").click(function(){
    $(this).closest(".test").find('.toHide').eq(0).hide();
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  (".first").click(function(){
 $(this).closest('.test').find('.toHide').hide();
   });
});
```